# Is there any REST API to enable/disable recording for a user in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Given a user principal name of user, Is there any API that can be used to enable/disable auto recording of meetings and calls for this particular user?

P.S: App is already created in AAD and any further permissions can also be assigned if needed.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently we don't have any such API to enable/disable auto recording of meetings and calls for this particular user.